# Will X be a binomial random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that 10 percent of the chips produced by a computer hardware manufacturer are defective. If we order 100 such chips, will X, the number of defective ones we receive, be a binomial random variable?

Comment: Test the conditions on that: independence and for every chip the same probability of being defective. If both are satisfied (it surely looks like it) then the answer is "yes".

Comment: Yes, assuming the chips are defective independently. There is always an "out of" for a Binomial variable. In this case it is the number of defectives out of 100.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! $X\sim Bin(100;\frac{1}{10})$

(Assuming independence...)